# Dependency Injection with collections

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, prism

So, lets say I have a view named `MyClassView` with a VM called `MyClassViewModel`, and these components are housed inside of an `IModule` implementation. I can easily register an instance of `MyClass` with the `UnityBootstrapper` and instruct a member of `MyClassViewModel` to retrieve it through injection.

Bootstrapper

```
this.Container.RegisterInstance<MyClass>("MyClass", new MyClass());
```

View Model

```
[Dependency("MyClass")]
public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
```

Simple enouigh. Now, lets say I want to go one step further and create a view for `MyClassCollection` that follows a similar injection strategy, but also allows my to inject each instance of `MyClass` into a `MyClassView`, essentially employing one module as an `ItemTemplate` for another module.

How would I go about this? Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Unity will happily inject all named registrations for a given interface into an array of that interface.

```
internal class MyCollectionViewModel
{
    public MyCollectionViewModel( IItem[] theItems )
    {
        // use theItems to fill your collection of ItemViewModels...
    }
}
```

The items have to be registered to the interface, of course:

```
Container.RegisterType<IItem, MyClass>( "model 1" );
Container.RegisterType<IItem, SomeOtherClass>( "model 2" );
```

BTW, I'd prefer constructor injection over property injection, because you're forced to fill in the dependencies. Property injection is for optional dependencies.